Testing a Python package dependent on user input credentials
I maintain a Python package for other data scientists and analysts in my company, which simplifies access to S3/Hive/Trino. The package works by taking their credentials, storing them using keyring, and using those credentials to access the various data resources in an abstracted manner.
I've ported the package to the new DevEx artifact thingy, part of which requires me to introduce unit tests to my package as part of the GitLab CI process.
How can I write appropriate tests, when the entire functionality of my package (reading from and writing to S3/Hive/Trino) is dependent on user input credentials? I obviously don't want to store my own in plain text, but I'm not sure how I can tell GitLab CI to retrieve the credentials from a secrets manager.

What kind of tests do you want to do? Unit test? E2E tests? Integration tests? Behavior tests? ...

What makes you think you can't test without credentials? In theory, you could also provide credentials for your test, too. You could mock out or replace your dependencies. Consider looking at localstack, for example, to test s3 interactions.
